# How can I get the total count of records in mongo db database using Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my Controller

```js
    const getCountofCenters = async (req, res) => {
        
        const result =  Center.countDocuments();
            
        await result.then(() => res.status(200).send(result))
            .catch((err) => {
                res.status(200).send(err)
            });   
    }
```

This is the Api call

```js
    router.get("/count", CenterController.getCountofCenters);
```

This is the output which I get from the Postman test, empty array

```json
    {}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqsVB.png)

Comment: Why do you try to send a promise to the user?`await result.then(data => res.status(200).send(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const getCountofCenters = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Center.countDocuments();
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

model.countDocuments returns a promise that you need to resolve so you can get the value of count
so the correct implementation on this within an async function is

```
await Center.countDocuments()
```

then sequentially you can return the response